# Breezingforms joomla workflow

Tags: joomla3.0, breezingforms

I'm using breezingforms and contentbuilder but I don't understand how to proceed with my workflow:

- A staff member submits a form (created by breezingforms) that needs to be viewed and approved two managers.

  - Each manager will be notified one at a time to authorize the form contents. Once the 1st manager authorize the form, the next manager will be automatically notified to authorize the form.
- Each manager authorizes the form contents by clicking "Approve" button and their details and date/time is recorded.